# How to persist input to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job in Jenkins which is parameterized. It takes a Choice parameter called "Delete" with "Yes" and "No" as choices. "Yes" is the default. The job gets triggered on commit, and the developers have to quickly make "No" the default when the build is in its quiet period or sometimes they need to quickly make "Yes" the default before the job kicks off. This sounds crazy!

The other option is for the developers to have a property file with just a Yes or No in it; When the job is triggered Jenkins reads the property file and proceeds with delete or not. This also is not very helpful because the developers need to change this file every time before they commit something.

Is there any way to persist their options, until someone changes it? For e.g, if the developer chooses "No" as the option, the job should continue to use "No" as the value for delete until someone changes it to "Yes". Any Jenkins plugin that can help persist the input?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a plugin that persists parameter choices. However, I can think of the following hand-made solution:

- Add a properties file with an initial `Delete=Yes|No` to Jenkins' workspace root.
    (The workspace root depends on *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> → *Workspace Root Directory* . I use `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`.)
- Add a script of your choice (Groovy, NodeJS, Windows batch, Shell) as first build step that uses:

  ```
  curl ${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/xml?xpath=*/action/cause
  ```

  (Check with an existing build's URL, what's returned in case of a manual build and in case of a commit-triggered build.)

  If the cause is a manual build write `Delete=<current value>` to the properties file in the workspace root, otherwise end the script.
- Add a build step *Inject environment variables* → *Properties File Path*: `../<properties file>` next to the above.

Such the same value is used unless somebody changes it:

- in the properties file in your workspace root
- when triggering a build manually and choosing the other value

If you want to avoid each of these, create a project with the same *Choice parameter* that simply does an:

```
echo Delete=<current value> > ../<properties file>
```